# Put multiple extra-deps package in stack

Tags: git, haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

I have a project relying on Amazonka, sadly my Region (`eu-west-3`), is only present on the current master branch and I was forced to create a special version in another git repository.

I have decided to put it in my `stack.yaml` as following:

```
extra-deps:
- git: https://github.com/myname/amazonka.git
  commit: ce2724ceb46c29ff5155552737c9fc6ee5183fc3
```

Sadly, since there is no cabal file, I end up with:

```
Cloning ce2724ceb46c29ff5155552737c9fc6ee5183fc3 from https://github.com/blackheaven/amazonka.git
No cabal file found for Repo from https://github.com/myname/amazonka.git, commit ce2724ceb46c29ff5155552737c9fc6ee5183fc3
```

Is there some arguments to add or a way to pass through it?

Comment: What do you mean "only present on the current master branch"? Which master branch in which repo? In your own repo? In the Amazonka repo? Why can't you use this master branch?

Comment: `stack` supports specifying a list of `subdirs` of a git repo. See https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#packages.